# Strtotime in MySQL query [basic PHP page]

Tags: php, mysql

I've been giving myself a basic refresher course in PHP without using template engines (although I've learnt some Smarty and Twig recently I felt I should keep practising basic PHP), and this is my basic page displaying a list of vehicles and when they were registered:

```
 <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "testing", "testingpass") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("cars1") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM autos") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 echo "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 "<tr>"; 
 //echo "<td>"date("d M Y",strtotime($info['registered']));"</td> "; 
 echo "<td><tr>".$info['make'] ." ".$info['model'] ."</td><tr> "; 
 } 
 echo "</table>"; 
 ?>
```

It works if the datetime is commented out, but if it's uncommented the page appears blank - I'm using MAMP as my webserver, latest PHP.

For a simple page this works well, but how should I format this date?
(I used the tutorial at http://erikastokes.com/mysql-help/display-mysql-dates-in-other-formats.php to try this).

What changes should I make to fix this problem with the date and time, as otherwise it works well as a basic MySQL php query.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top. your errors are off by default.

Comment: learn how to to use `echo`, read documentation

Comment: do a var_dump($info]); and you will see what is wrong

Comment: DOTS: echo "<td>".date("d M Y",strtotime($info['registered']))."</td>";

Answer (score 2):

it should be like this

```
echo "<td>".date("d M Y",strtotime($info['registered']))."</td> ";
```

You have to use `.` for concantinate string.

Comment: he also has `"<tr>";` without `echo`, you might want to point that too

Answer (score 0):

First off, the reason your screen is blank, is because most default PHP installs have error reporting turned off. You'll need to edit your php.ini file to fix that. Open and search for `display_errors` and change it.

Second, the first error you're missing is you just have `"<tr>"` with no `echo` before it.

The second error you're most likely not seeing is that you're missing a concatenating operator `.`

```
echo "<td>"date("d M Y",strtotime($info['registered']));"</td> "
```

should be

```
echo "<td>" . date("d M Y",strtotime($info['registered'])) . "</td> "
```

Comment: `error_reporting()` would not work here, as he would need to have `display_errors` enabled.  Also, you could not set it at runtime, as this was a parse error.

Comment: Good call, changed to have OP look for that in his php.ini